# Why does innerHTML rearrange HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Here's my HTML:

```
    <template id="team-members">

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);">
                <font color="#0000ff">[[TITLE]]</font>
            </span>
        </h3>

        <table class="[[ITEM-CLASS]]">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="pic" width="30%" />
                <col />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <!-- CONTAINER FOR ITEMS -->
                <span data-template="team-member" data-records="[[RECORDS]]"></span>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </template>
```

Javascript:

```
const header = document.querySelector("template#team-members");
const myHTML = header.innerHTML;
```

Output:

```
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);">
                <font color="#0000ff">[[TITLE]]</font>
            </span>
        </h3>
        <span data-template="team-member" data-records="[[RECORDS]]"></span><table class="[[ITEM-CLASS]]">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="pic" width="30%">
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <!-- CONTAINER FOR ITEMS -->
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

As you can see, the span containing attribute `data-template="team-member"` got moved to a different line.

How to fix?

Comment: Because your HTML is invalid and the browser tries its best to make sense of it. A [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) isn't allowed to have a `<span>` tag as a direct child. It only allows zero or more `<tr>` elements.

Comment: @Ivar Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Is there any other way for js to retrieve the raw html, besides `innerHTML`?

Comment: You don't show what you do with `myHTML` but you could append it directly with `parentElement.appendChild(document.querySelector("template#team-members"));`. But it still doesn't fix invalid HTML.

Comment: @mykaf Thx, but unclear how your suggestion applies. I'm not trying to *append* the innerHTML to the tbody, i'm trying to *retrieve* the innerHTML from the tbody.

Comment: It's unclear what you are attempting to do with this innerHTML. What are you retrieving it for?

Comment: You might be able to load the source via AJAX as a string, then use use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) to parse it as XML and get the content like that. I don't think it is possible to get the raw HTML from the current page directly. (Unfortunately I currently don't have time to write a full answer.)

Comment: @mykaf The inner `span` is a placeholder. Javascript replaces that inner `span` with a bunch of `tr` tags.

Answer (score 0):

*Another user kindly posted this answer in comments.*

Because your HTML is invalid and the browser tries its best to make sense of it. A `<tbody>` isn't allowed to have a `<span>` tag as a direct child. It only allows zero or more `<tr>` elements.